# How do I scrape data that is on multiple pages without it failing?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I'm really new to scrapping data and I am having trouble scrapping multiple pages.
I'm trying to get the title of an episode as well as the rating for the episode.

I am only successful in getting the first page scrapped and then it won't work after that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0386676/episodes?season=1'

next_season = "//*[@id='load_next_episodes']"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

for season in range(1,10):
    i = 1
    episodes = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('info')
    for episode in episodes:
        title = episode.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="episodes_content"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[{i}]/div[2]/strong/a').text
        rating = episode.find_element_by_class_name('ipl-rating-star__rating').text
        print(title, rating)
        i += 1

    browser.find_element_by_xpath(next_season).click()
browser.close()
```

My output looks like this:

```
Pilot 7.4
Diversity Day 8.2
Health Care 7.7
The Alliance 7.9
Basketball 8.3
Hot Girl 7.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the page details without clicking on `season button` as well.
You can first get all the `season number` from the `dropdown box` and then iterate.
You can create list and append the data in it and then can iterate at the end or can load into a `dataframe` and then export into CSV file.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0386676/episodes?season=1")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
selectSeason=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#bySeason')))
select=Select(selectSeason)
allSeasons=[option.get_attribute('value') for option in select.options] #get all season numbers
print(allSeasons)
title=[]
ratings=[]
for season in allSeasons:
    url="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0386676/episodes?season={}".format(season)
    print(url)
    driver.get(url)
    for e in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".info"))):
        title.append(e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[itemprop='name']").text)
        ratings.append(e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ipl-rating-star.small .ipl-rating-star__rating").text)
    
for t , r in zip(title, ratings):
    print(t + " --- " + r)
```

**Output**:

[image]